# Hookan and permission on front end template

Tags: members, permissions

We have about 30+ member groups (schools) and about 15 channels (books).

After logging in at the front end, member groups should have access to the channels we set. For the moment we use snippets to do it, but its very hard for a non tech person to manage it. So when we came across Hookan module from de Beer, it looks like the perfect fit to manage it (instead of the snippets). This module is purchased and installed and looks like it works well.

I only one the user groups to view, no edit or create anything.

On the front end template, how do I code the persmission to only display channels (books) the user group who have access to?

I would appreciate if you could just send me off in the right direction. I'm just stuck at the moment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control access to channel content based on group membership in native EE. So far as I know Hooblong is the only module that gives that kind of control. HooKan can't help either since HooKan only makes normal `control panel features more accessible.

With native EE, if you want members of group A to only access entries belonging to channel X, for example, then your template must use the `channel="X"` parameter. To make that dynamic, you will need a conditional something like `{if logged_in_group_id == 'groupA_ID'}Something{/if}`in your template around your channel entries tag. Unfortunately you would need this for each channel/group combination, so your template can become quite complex.

[Hooblong](https://www.debeer.com/index.php/hooblong) just takes care of all that once you have set it up

Comment: Hi, 
for the moment, I have use a code like this:
{if snippet_1 ~ '/\b'.logged_in_member_group.'\b/'}something{/if} and inside snippet_1 I put the member group id(s).
So what I understand from your answer, I still have to use condition in the template, but managing who got the access will not be done via the snippet I'm currently doing now but via Hooblong? 
This what I hoped and it would help managing who got access to what and when I add a new channel I just need to ad a new conditionals in the template.